# Putting css transitions in variable

Tags: css

I have the same transition in multiple classes in my code. Is there any way to put them all in a variable or something? I would just like the code to look a bit cleaner.

Here is what the css looks like currently:

```
.logincontent {
    opacity: 1;

    transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}

.passwordcontent {
    opacity: 0;

    transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}

.logincontent.switch {
    opacity: 0;

    transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}

.passwordcontent.switch {
    opacity: 1;

    transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}
```

This is what I would like it to look like (but of course you can add a variable thing in here somewhere):

```
.logincontent {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: MyAnimationVariable;
}

.passwordcontent {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: MyAnimationVariable;
}

.logincontent.switch {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: MyAnimationVariable;
}

.passwordcontent.switch {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: MyAnimationVariable;
}
```

Comment: show code NOT image of code!

Comment: Do you need to support older browsers? Neither of those two prefixes has been needed for transitions for several years.

Comment: Ah I did not know that! I just copied them from somewhere. I will remove them. That basically then solves my problem I guess haha

Comment: consdier class, they are made for this purpose .. one class to define the transition and you are good

Comment: @TemaniAfif OP simply needs to understand basic CSS concepts. They already have the classes. They simply  need to be *Grouped*.

Comment: @Martin am not talking about grouping, even grouping isn't a good solution ... the good solution is to define one class for the transition then use it where you need a transition but not append 100 classes that shares the same one

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes that is a totally plausable solution; it is solving the same problem from a different angle; instead of grouping, adding HTML classes and CSS class definitions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this answer is exactly what you're looking for. It's a basic tenet of CSS and does not need any JS (if I've misunderstood the question please clarify!).

You can "Group" class references so that only one line of CSS code appears but is referenced to each applicable class, object or pseudo-class, (etc.):

> When you group CSS selectors, you apply the same styles to several different elements without repeating the styles in your style sheet. Instead of having two or three or even more CSS rules, all of which do the same thing, you have a single CSS rule.

From [this source](https://www.lifewire.com/grouping-multiple-css-selectors-3467065). See also [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/).

## Original:

> ```
>  .logincontent {
>      opacity: 1;
>  
>      transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; }
>  
>  .passwordcontent {
>      opacity: 0;
>  
>      transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; }
>  
>  .logincontent.switch {
>      opacity: 0;
>  
>      transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; }
>  
>  .passwordcontent.switch {
>      opacity: 1;
>  
>      transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
>      -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; }
> ```

Line count: 27.

## Grouped:

(*The prefixes are retained*)
As pointed out in comments, the `nn.switch` class rules are not required but I have retained them for the OP to understand the broad logic process at work.

```
.logincontent,
.passwordcontent.switch {
    opacity: 1;
}

.passwordcontent,
.logincontent.switch {
     opacity: 0;
}

.logincontent,
.passwordcontent,
.logincontent.switch,
.passwordcontent.switch {
     transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
     -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out all; 
     -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}
```

Line count: 19.

Comment: I don't think the line count is the reference to say the code is better ... you may notice that you have useless definition ... why adding transtion to `.logincontent` and `.logincontent.switch` ? there is no need, only the main class need the transition

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do agree entirely however I just used the line count to show the benefits of avoided repetitons in the CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`custom-properties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to put `0.5s ease-out all;` into a variable:

```
:root {
  --my-transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
```

If you want to keep vendor prefixes - you can add helper class like `.my-transition` and mix it with your html:

```
.my-transition {
    transition: --my-transition;
    -moz-transition: --my-transition;
    -webkit-transition: --my-transition;
}
```

Check how it works:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('p, h1, h2').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.color = 'green';
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
:root {
  --my-transition: .5s ease-out all;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.my-transition {
  transition: var(--my-transition);
  -moz-transition: var(--my-transition);
  -webkit-transition: var(--my-transition);
}

p {
  transition: var(--my-transition);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my-transition">Header 1</h1>
<h2 class="my-transition">Header 2</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: According the to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var), `var` is experimental technology. If you need variables; then, use just use a CSS Pre-processer. Much safer than experimental techologies.

Comment: @Tyler CSS Custom Properties is a W3C [**Candidate Recommendation**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) and they're [supported in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) (except IE).

Comment: It's still marked as experimental from a trust worthy source. If it's marked as experimental you should expect that its behavior may change in the future.

Comment: @Tyler Four years later, there's no trace of 'experimental' in the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) you quoted. Apparently, MDN took the time to reconsider and update their documentation accordingly. You may want to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable as below

```js
$(document).on("click", ".logincontent", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("switch");
});
```

```css
:root {
    --anim: 0.5s ease-out all;
}

.logincontent {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: var(--anim); 
}

.passwordcontent {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: var(--anim); 
}

.logincontent.switch {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: var(--anim); 
}

.passwordcontent.switch {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: var(--anim);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logincontent">Test</div>
```

Comment: you simply make the code bigger ... a simple definition with a class will be fine and the class can be reused

Comment: Don't use jquery for something as simple as a css question please

Comment: According the to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var), `var` is experimental technology. If you need variables; then, use just use a CSS Pre-processer. Much safer than experimental techologies.